# Using headless JBrowserDriver with Selenium server and phpunit

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, phpunit, headless

JBrowserDriver is said to be headless webkit which I wish to use with my phpunit. I dont know how to configure it to that it can be used.

I tried it with selenium server standalone and calling it from my unit:
`$this->setBrowser('jBrowserDriver');`

and the server complaints:

`Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: The best matching driver provider org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver can't create a new driver instance for Capabilities [{browserName=jbrowserdriver}]`

I have tried setting CLASSPATH but that also does not help selenium find the class in `jbrowserdriver-0.8.2.jar`.

How do I this setup so selenium can start using it and later phpunit can also use it. I am using MacOS.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions at https://github.com/MachinePublishers/jBrowserDriver#usage? Please also post your setup code.

Comment: tis my first try to use phpunit+selenium. the jbrowserdriver usage is giving example usage it in Java. But i have no java in my setup. https://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/selenium.html if you see the first example unit, thats what i'm trying, only i want to use jbrowserdriver instead of default browser. that is everything.

Comment: Hi, I created jBrowserDriver. Can you try version 0.8.6 available via Maven? I don't have PHPUnit to test. I changed the browser name to be "jBrowserDriver" ... Note that not all config options will be available to you as I haven't yet implemented Capabilities

Comment: Thanks. I download the 3.8.6 jar. How to have the jar loaded by selenium standalone server (who does not normally recognize this browser name)? this is where i struggle. (im not a java dev ;)

Comment: @thevikas I looked into it some more. I need to implement RemoteWebDriver for this to work. You can follow when that's done by watching this issue: https://github.com/MachinePublishers/jBrowserDriver/issues/35

Answer (score 1):

jBrowserDriver will support this in the upcoming version 0.10.0. To ensure you can load this, put jBrowserDriver and all of its dependencies on the classpath. Also use "jbrowserdriver" (lowercase) as the name, `$this->setBrowser('jbrowserdriver');`

FYI, to make a WebDriver available in Selenium Server, on your classpath have a directory named `META-INF/services` containing a file named `org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverProvider` and inside of that file list the package/class name of the concrete class that implements `org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverProvider` or extends `org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider`. (For details, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html). However, v0.10.0+ of jBrowserDriver will do this for you out of the box.

(disclosure: I'm that project's owner)